# rails 6 react error importing component module not found can't resolve

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I'm trying to import /app/javascript/components/Videochat.js into app/javascript/packs/index.js but getting the error module not found Can't resolve Videochat ...
index.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDom from 'react-dom'
import Videochat from '../components/Videochat'

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
   ReactDom.render(
      <Videochat/>,
      document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')),
   )
})
```

Videochat.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom"
import CreateRoom from "./routes/CreateRoom"
import Room from "./routes/Room"

class Videochat extends React.Component {
    render () {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={CreateRoom} />
        <Route path="/room/:roomID" component={Room} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
 }
}

export default Videochat
```

Comment: Can you show us the directory tree where index.js is located please?

Comment: It's in app/javascript/packs There are no subfolders app/javascript/ contains channels components images packs stylesheets

Comment: I really don't know how to show a folder structure on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the component name from Videochat to App
It seems the presence of App.js in the components folder is of great significance In my case I was importing the Videochat component but not the App component even though it was present